# Pip install issue with egg fragments that lead to an UNKNOWN installation of a package

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

I have been handed a MacBook Pro and need to ensure that some of our Python 2.7 scripts run on that laptop that run smoothly on Windows machines.

The MacBook is pretty old, 2008, OS X 10.11.6

I am having trouble installing certain packages with pip install on this laptop and am seeking help here as a last resort.
First off, Python 2.7.10 is installed and runs smoothly.
Pip install works too, but not for all packages.
First off, I installed the python-vlc package:

```
pip install python-vlc --user
```

Finished without errors. Then I run our script which imports the package using import vlc

```
python script.py
```

leads to

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "script.py", line 30, in 
>       import vlc
>     File "/Users/admin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/vlc/**init**.py", line 4, in 
>       from vlc.helper import tell
>     File "/Users/admin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/vlc/helper.py", line 4, in 
>       import applescript
>     File "/Users/admin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/applescript/**init**.py", line 3, in 
>       import only
>   **ImportError: No module named only**

Seemed like I need to install the package only:

```
pip install only --user
```

which lead to

> Collecting only
>   Installing collected packages: only
>   Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 366, in run
>       use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/**init**.py", line 49, in install_given_reqs
>       **kwargs
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 760, in install
>       use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 382, in move_wheel_files
>       warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 326, in move_wheel_files
>       assert info_dir, "%s .dist-info directory not found" % req
>   AssertionError: only .dist-info directory not found

So, tried to manually download it

```
pip download only
```

Leads to

> Collecting only
>     Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/jp/6s5zvb6s0kb19qdgy33sbkf40000gq/T/pip-download-C2CG6U/only/setup.py) egg_info for package only produced metadata for project name unknown. **Fix your #egg=only fragments.**
>   Successfully downloaded unknown

I'm not quite sure how to address this issue. If I try to go ahead with the installation regardless with

```
pip install only-1.0.2.tar.gz --user
```

> Processing ./only-1.0.2.tar.gz
>   Building wheels for collected packages: UNKNOWN
>     Running setup.py bdist_wheel for UNKNOWN ... done
>     Stored in directory: /Users/admin/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/13/bb/2c/bbbba0f8e56cc66e91a845dc17f9ba7045e5871aa88062798f
>   Successfully built UNKNOWN
>   Installing collected packages: UNKNOWN
>     Found existing installation: UNKNOWN 0.0.0
>       Uninstalling UNKNOWN-0.0.0:
>         Successfully uninstalled UNKNOWN-0.0.0
>   Successfully installed UNKNOWN-0.0.0

Leads to this 'unknown' installation, as it shows up in pip list. Now, googling showed that some had the same issue and they could resolve it by updating setuptools. The setuptools version on this laptop is 1.1.6, so I attempt to update it

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade --user
```

> Collecting setuptools
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/a1/ba6fb41367b375f5cb653d1317d8ca263c636cff6566e2da1b0da716069d/setuptools-40.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   **applescript 0.0.1 requires only, which is not installed.**
>   **applescript 0.0.1 requires temp, which is not installed.**
>   Installing collected packages: setuptools
>   Successfully installed setuptools-40.5.0

It says it successfully installed setuptools 40.5, but it did not as pip list remains unchanged. I'm back at square one because I need to install the package only (and temp), but that leads to an "unknown" installation.
Applescript is version 0.0.1. I cannot upgrade it because it attempts to install the package only, which fails.

My guess is that I need to address the egg-info issue when installing only (and temp) package, but I don't know how to. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this installation issue?

Answer (score 20):

I ran this

`pip install setuptools --upgrade`

...and then installed again when I had #egg\UNKNOWN install of a package.

Comment: I'm having this same UNKNOWN package being installed for a different project (1.0.5 of Pytweening) and updating setuptools did not fix it.

Comment: Doesn't work in Python2.7. Tries to run a script that has the `f""` syntax, which won't work in Python2.7.

Answer (score 5):

I found the workaround. If people have a similar problem, I hope this will help:

I manually wrote a setup.py file according to setuptools specifications.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='only',
      version='1.0.2',
      packages=find_packages(),
     )
```

Then go into the extracted folder of the downloaded package (in this case after pip download only, into only-1.0.2 directory). Execute

```
python setup.py install
```

And you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error, tried this

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

and then

```
pip3 install pandas
```

and it worked

Comment: Just to confirm this has solved the issue for me.